# smart tokenizer in c

Tags: c, tokenize

I have to write a tokenizer in c/c++ such that i have to parse a string of the form

```
char pSignature[] = "work.\\top =>\\p1 =:5:p2=:10:=>interface_ports:=dut";
```

and populate the pair of \p1 5 and p2 10 etc.can someone suggest me any good method.problem with using strtok is that how to end it before =>interface_ports occurs.
Below is the code i have written:

```
int main() {
  char pSignature[] = "work.\\top =>\\p1 =:5:p2=:10:=>interface_ports:=dut";
  char* mParamName = NULL;
  char* mParamVal = NULL;
  char* sTemp = pSignature;
  bool bIsLibState = true;
  bool bIsModState = false;
  bool bIsEscaped = false;
  while (*sTemp != '\0') {
    // Extract library ..
    if (bIsLibState) {
      if (*sTemp == '.') {
        bIsLibState = false;
        bIsModState = true;
      }
      sTemp++;
    }
    else if (bIsModState) {
    // Extract moduleName..
      if (*sTemp == '\\') {
        bIsEscaped = true;
      }
      if (bIsEscaped) {
        if (*sTemp == ' ') {
          bIsModState = false;
          bIsEscaped = false;
          sTemp++;
          sTemp += 2;
          break;
        }
        else 
          sTemp++;
      }
      else {
        if (*(sTemp+1) == '=' && *(sTemp+2) == '>') {
          bIsModState = false;
          sTemp++;
          sTemp += 2;
          break;
        }
        else
          sTemp++;
      }
    }
  }

  char* tmp = sTemp;
  char* mStr = sTemp;
  bool bEscaped = false;
  while(tmp != NULL)
  {
    if (*tmp == '\\') {
      tmp = strtok(mStr, " ");
        bEscaped  = true;
    }
    else
      tmp = strtok(mStr, "=:");
    if (!strcmp(tmp,">interface_ports"))
      break;
    mStr = NULL;
    mParamName = tmp;

    tmp = strtok(mStr, "=:");
    if (!strcmp(tmp,">interface_ports"))
      break;
    mParamVal = tmp;
    cout << mParamName <<"  " << mParamVal << endl;
    //if (mParamName && mParamVal) {
    //  symCharPair* paramPair = new symCharPair(VeIntern(mParamName), mParamVal);
    //  pParamValueList->AddTail(paramPair);
    //}
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: somebody please help..:(

Comment: You'll have to be clearer about what constitutes a token here.

Comment: Be carefull, the second argument of `strtok` is a **set** of delimiters. When writing `strtok(mStr, "=:");`, the next token will be every characters between `mStr` and `'='` **or** `':'` (or `'\0'`). Also we don't understand how you want to tokenize this string.

Answer (score 1):

If your input string is always of this form

```
work.\\top =>\\p1 =:5:p2=:10:=>interface_ports:=dut
```

Then you could do something simpler:

```
 #include <string.h>

 const char *input = "work.\\top =>\\p1 =:5:p2=:10:=>interface_ports:=dut";

 // find first occurrence of "=>"
 const char *start = strstr(input, "=>");

 // find first occurrence of ":=>"
 const char *end= strstr(input, ":=>");

 if (start == NULL || end == NULL)
     exit(-1);

 int length = end - start - 2 ; // the -2 is to skip the "=>"
 char *pairs = malloc(length + 1); // +1 for the terminating \0
 strncpy(pairs, start + 2, length);
```

Now `pairs` should contain `\p1 =:5:p2=:10` which you might be able to deal with easier.

Comment: yeah i can use that but the problem is since the name itself can have these characters so i can not use this method..

Answer (score 0):

Read [books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/browse/ref=sr_tc_2_1?node=3971&ie=UTF8&qid=1325791030&sr=8-2-tc) about [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) techniques, notably used in compilation.

Learn how to make recursive descent parsers, and perhaps use generators like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (or yacc), [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)

Comment: i have to use it in my program in my c code..so its not part of paring

Comment: You are doing parsing. If you have to use `strtok` read twice, and carefully, its documentation. If you can avoid using it, learn how parsers work. Don't expect us to do your homework.

Comment: Not very helpful answer. You don't need a lot of theory if you just want to split a string on delimiters...